# How can I access components of list elements in R

Tags: arrays, r, list

I have a ragged list that I would like to work with. i.e. I would like to use an apply function to quickly and simply pull out elements from the lists. The following code attempts to approximate my situation:

```
vec1 <- c("B","D","E","NA")
vec2 <- c("B","D","E","NA")
vec3 <- c("B","C","E","NA")


write.table(vec1, file="./vec1.csv", sep=",", quote=F)
write.table(vec2, file="./vec2.csv", sep=",", quote=F)
write.table(vec3, file="./vec3.csv", sep=",", quote=F)

vectors.files <- list.files(path=getwd(),recursive=F, pattern=paste("*.csv",sep=""))

vectors.list <- lapply(vectors.files, read.csv)
```

How would I then be able to create a new object that was for example the second row of each list element in vectors.list?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: You mean something like `lapply(vectors.list, `[`, 2, 1)` (or `lapply(vectors.list, function(x) x[2, ])`)?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Thanks for the suggestion when I try: x <- lapply(vectors.list, [, 2, 1)
Error: unexpected '[' in "x <- lapply(vectors.list, ["

Comment: Sorry. I always forget that backticks get stripped by default in comments. It should be `\`[\``.

Comment: @AnandaMahto "[" works too

Comment: @baptiste, I was just playing with this syntax when I saw your comment. `lapply(vectors.list, "[", 2, 1)` doesnt work for me, presumably because the default `[` is used and only passes the `i` argument, but `lapply(vectors.list, "[.data.frame", 1, 2)` does work for `i`, `j`, `drop`, but vectors.list isnt a data frame. What is the proper method to pass `j` to `[` along with `i`? I'm not seeing the right method from `methods('[')`

Comment: I suppose `lapply(mtcars, '[.data.frame', 1, 2)` vs `lapply(mtcars, '[', 1, 2)` would be a better, reproducible example, but not exactly since mtcars actually *is* a data frame. I am wondering about lists in general

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Thanks again. This gives me a list with the 3 values but also the other non-selected values as Levels. Is there any way to flatten this so there is just an array or data frame with the selected elements?

Comment: If you're dealing with single-column `data.frame`s, like you are in your example, then perhaps just `sapply(vectors.list, function(x) as.character(x[2, ]))`, otherwise, you might need to add an `unlist` in there too.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Thank you again. In the end I had to as.data.frame(unlist(x)) to get just the values. I'll try this out on my real data. Could you please submit your code as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're after as the final output format, but you might want to try variations on the following template:

```
lapply(vectors.list, function(x) x[2, , drop = FALSE])
# [[1]]
#   x
# 2 D
# 
# [[2]]
#   x
# 2 D
# 
# [[3]]
#   x
# 2 C
```

Here, we've just passed an anonymous function (`function(x)`) to the items in your "vectors.list". In this case, we've used basic subsetting using `[` to extract the second row. The `drop = FALSE` is to retain the `data.frame` structure since the result is a single-column `data.frame` (which normally simplifies to a `vector`).

Note that the `data.frame`s in the resulting `list` still have all the original `levels` for the "x" `factor`. Use `droplevels` if you want to retain only the specific factor in that row.

Compare:

```
str(lapply(vectors.list, function(x) x[2, , drop = FALSE]))
# List of 3
#  $ :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "B","D","E": 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "B","D","E": 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "B","C","E": 2
str(lapply(vectors.list, function(x) droplevels(x[2, , drop = FALSE])))
# List of 3
#  $ :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: Factor w/ 1 level "D": 1
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: Factor w/ 1 level "D": 1
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: Factor w/ 1 level "C": 1
```

You may also want to explore `as.character(unlist(x[2, ])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your vectors in a data frame you can subset.

```
> df <- data.frame(vectors.list)
> row2 <- df[2,]
> row2
  x x.1 x.2
2 D   D   C
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I have a ragged set of data so have to work with lists.